# HTTP status 302 and subsequent redirect

Tags: tls, http, url-redirection

I have sent a HTTP GET request to google.com and I get a 302 status. Now the location : url in http header is an `http://` address, instead of https. When the browser visits this address I get back a 302 redirect again but with an https address in the location field of http header. The browser then visits this address and https connection is established. Also the IP of the first server which sent me a 302 redirect is different from the second 302 redirect sender. Finally the server with which I establish an https connection has a different ip.

My question is why do I not get a https redirect in the first 302 reply?

Also, I am using a program which sends an HTML GET request to a server and gets 
back the response. How can I simulate this chain of 302 redirects to reach the 
final server which returns an https page?

The program takes as input `./execfile_name host_name page`.

Every time I supply the google.com hostname it connects to the same server (same IP). How can I get it to connect to the next server in the chain leading to the final one?

Comment: Have you bookmarked the final URL? That may work better.

Comment: would you provide the request and response headers for both examples?

Answer (score -1):

> why do I not get a https redirect in the first 302 reply

Bad programming on the part of of whoever designed the system - bobbing out of https makes it trivial to carry out a MITM attack on the connection.

> How can I get it to connect to the next server in the chain leading to the final one

Use a better program. HTTP is deceptively complex. You can point a simple socket adapter at port 80 on a webserver, type in 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' and get a sensible response nine times out of ten - but HTTP allows for more compex stuff like chunked encoding and redirects before you even start to consider session management and intrusion prevention.

Personally I use wget or curl from the command line (both of which can automatically follow redirects) or libcurl in scripts/programs.

Comment: Why? And what would you use to script/record an HTTP interaction?

Comment: My bad @symcbean. I didn't realize that the question was about both browser and script behavior.